# "complete" as a noun

Tags: grammar, nouns, vocabulary

I came across the definition of *complete* on [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/complete#Noun). To my surprise, *complete* is used as a noun. I assumed it might be a rare/archaic usage, but there are frequent quotations from books.

Is it part of the standard vocabulary to understand a sentence like:

> Don’t get discouraged if you’re on a job that is difficult to get
> **completes** on!

Comment: And? I see no question mark in your 'question'.

Comment: I'd say it's a neologism that hasn't made it into the usual dictionaries (AHD, M-W, Collins, Lexico, CD ...) yet. Business jargon. Or, with a different subsense, flooring jargon:  'A few ... need completes that don’t sparkle. Some need completes that do. Some need the tones in the wood to “pop.” ... One of the most noteworthy visual qualities of a completion is its sheen' [[FlooringSurgeons.co.uk](https://www.flooringsurgeons.co.uk/finishing-your-hardwood-floors-to-get-just-the-look-you-want/)]

Comment: It can be part of an NP. I met a person named Complete in the past.

Comment: @banuyayi that's a proper noun, not a noun. Every word can be a proper noun.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wiktionary isn't a good source of information about how normal a usage is. Having an entry in Wiktionary just means somebody edited that page and nobody bothered to edit it back. There is no real indication that this is a widespread usage. No other dictionary I have looked at has a noun definition of complete - even the two ancient dictionaries recommended for "further reading" in the definition don't include it. Wiktionary cites only three examples. (And also says it refers only to surveys, not tasks as is the case in your example.)

It is possible that this is a "neologism" that has not been accepted by other dictionaries - however the only difference between a "neologism" and a "mistake" is whether the people reading what you wrote accept it or not (or whether people in the future someday come to accept it).

**There is already a perfectly good noun "completion" which will be acceptable by everyone.**

I would caution against using "complete" in this way unless you don't really care about the correctness of your English or are sure your readers will be OK with it.

Comment: It sounds like business/sales jargon. Only use it if your boss uses it.